# Can we change value of global variable this.classvariable?

Tags: java

If I assigned this.bussfee=busfee in the Student constructor below, then this.busfee variable value should be 14000. But actually it stays with the same value - 4000. Could you help me understand why?

```
public class PrintStudent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //here i m calling constructor with value 14000
        Student st3=new Student("Rohit",35,14000);
        Student st4=new Student();

    }
}

public class Student { 
    //These variable are global variable 
    int Busfee; 

    protected Student () { 
        this.Busfee=4000; 
    } 

    protected Student (String Name,int Age,int Busfee) { 
        this.Name=Name; 
        this.Age=Age; 
        this.Busfee=Busfee; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: My Question is if i have done assigned this.bussfee=busfee then this.busfee variable value should change to 14000 . but actually it is same 4000 ,

Comment: added a comment into the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Where do you see it to be 4000? Can you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: *"These variable are global variable"* — Not quite. The `busfee` is an instance variable. You are constructing two `Student` instances, and each instance has it's own value of `busfee`. Oh, and: you should stick to the Java Naming Conventions: variable names must start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: The second constructor assigns the value, the first uses 4000. If your Busfee is static then the second overrides it.

Answer (score 0):

The second constructor assigns the value, the first uses 4000. If your Busfee is static then the second overrides it.

The result from the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //here i m calling constructor with value 14000
    Student st3=new Student("Rohit",35,14000);
    System.out.println(st3.Busfee);
    Student st4=new Student();
    System.out.println(st3.Busfee);
    System.out.println(st4.Busfee);
}
```

If not static it prints: 14000, 14000, 4000

If static it prints: 14000, 4000, 4000